# spring multiple response file and view

Tags: java, spring, controller, request, response

I have a requirement where once request is complete spring controller shall send two responses.

1. A PDF file for for download
2. Some messages for the screen.

Is it possible to achieve this in single response object. If not any suggestions.

Comment: What about you genenerate the file and put it in a download directory on the server and in the response simply provide a link for the download of the generated file along with your "screen messages".

Comment: User requirement and plus the request execution is one time operation. So the content of pdf might change for another request.

Comment: So what? You can keep pdfs in the folder for a while and discard them after certain amount of time. Every pdf there could belong to a specific user/request.

Comment: Yes its an option. And if expected solution is not found then will be implemented. But I am just curious to know if its possible in single response.

Comment: You can put whatever you want in a response object. After all this is just the HTTP protocol. The question is who is the consumer of the response? If its the browser then it is expecting a single thing, either HTML,XML,JSON,or a file. The browser would not know how to handle two things in the response. For that you would need to consume your own response in a different way, parhaps an Ajax callback. But honestly, I would't know how to deal with the file in this way.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @EdwinDalorzo. Lets see if someone turns up with the solution.

Comment: No, it is not possible. You can see some explanations here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18275043/spring-download-file-and-redirect/18279634#18279634